# FluentMigrator Postgres(Npgsql) quotes

Tags: postgresql, double-quotes, npgsql, fluent-migrator

if use fluentmigrator with postgres it generate code like this

```
CREATE TABLE public."Sample"...
```

because of this i must use double quotes for every sequence

```
SELECT * FROM public.Sample <--- Error
SELECT * FROM public."Sample" <--- OK
```

How i can turn off double quoter?

more informating description https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/issues/687

Comment: The easiest way is to avoid mixed-case identifiers. (identifiers are case-insignificant in SQL, unless quoted)

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look at this myself and the issue is that FluentMigrator has the quotes hard coded in basically..... as per the current version.

The only way forward is to download and modify the source code yourself.

Its pretty well made you'll need to look a the PostgresQuoter.cs class for example and override some of the base quoting methods.

I haven't completely modded the whole project, only works on the first pass and hope to complete the rest of the changes later this week. 
If it isn't too hacky i'll see if can't give you the files to modify.

Answer (score 2):

In latest version 3.3.2 you can disable the quoting via `PostgresOptions` "Force Quote" parameter, which annoyingly defaults to 'true' but can be toggled off.

Argument for the `dotnet fm` tool to turn the behavior off:

`--processor-switches "Force Quote=false"`

See https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/blob/v3.3.2/src/FluentMigrator.Runner.Postgres/Processors/Postgres/PostgresOptions.cs

https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/runners/dotnet-fm.html#-s--processor-switches-processor_switches

The same can be done with the "in-process" approach by setting `ProcessorOptions` on the IDBMigrationRunner instance while configuring the runner:

Small snippet:

```
        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddFluentMigratorCore()
            .ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
                .AddPostgres()
                // ...
                .ConfigureGlobalProcessorOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.ProviderSwitches = "Force Quote=false";
                })
                // ...
```

For context see:

https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/migration-runners.html?tabs=vs-pkg-manager-console

Answer (score 1):

This is really only an issue if you're not consistently using lowercase. Postgres is case sensitive. Postgresql treats identifiers case-insensitively when not quoted (it actually folds them to lowercase internally), and case sensitively when quoted. Using always lowercase you are safe. If you're using camelCase or PascalCase, however, it means that you will always need to be consistent: either quote identifiers always or never.

Restated, if you're naming things using lowercase as a convention you won't have the double quote problem.  If you're using uppercase you're stuck with the double quote problem.  Hope this helps. Best of luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely get rid of double quotes, then:

1. Create derived class from `PostgresQuoter`

   ```
   public class NoQuoteQuoter : PostgresQuoter
   {
       public NoQuoteQuoter(PostgresOptions options) : base(options)
       {
       }
       protected override bool ShouldQuote(string name)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add it via dependency injection to startup

   ```
   return new ServiceCollection()
       .AddScoped<PostgresQuoter, NoQuoteQuoter>()
   ```

Comment: Doing this for some reason also causes it to not see if the table is already created

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this problem myself, it is mentioned by a number of other people, but I want to reiterate the point and also clarify especially if you are coming from SQL Server.

First of all, if you are not mixing different databases and only using PG then the EASIEST way to stop the problem. **Don't use mixed case!** simply just make things all lowercase

eg

```
Create.Table("users")
```

Now when querying you can do any of the following

```
select * from users
select * from Users
select * from USERS
```

They all do the same thing.

You need to do this with columns as well.

the reason PG has the quotes is that it supports the idea of a quoted symbol that has to match the casing exactly

Possibly there is a hook in FluentMigrator where you can enforce lowercase ( ie, just `.ToLower()` all the names)